# Holomorphic maps between smooth algebraic curves

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am looking for a reference for the following statement:

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$. Every holomorphic function $f: X \to \mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ is in fact a morphism of projective varieties.

Comment: Looks like it's a consequence of GAGA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canoncial reference for this is probably Prop. 15 in §19 of Serre, J-P, *Géométrie algébrique et géométrie analytique*, Annales de l’institut Fourier **6** (1956), p. 1-42.

The statement reads

> Toute application holomorphe $f$ d'une variété algébrique compacte $X$ dans une variété algébrique $Y$ est régulière.

In English:

> Every holomorphic map $f$ from a compact algebraic variety $X$ to an algebraic variety $Y$ is regular.

Here "compact" of course refers to the analytic topology.